# Which number replaces the question mark in <16, 2, 11, 6, 9, 4, 14, ?>

Tags: pattern, visual

I came across a puzzle (posed by my friends) that looked like this:

> Which Number Replaces the Question Mark?
>
> ```
>      6
>   11 | 9
>     \|/
> 2 -- ⬤ -- 4
>     /|\
>   16 | 14
>      ?
> ```
>
> - A. 1
> - B. 2
> - C. 3
> - D. 5

Does anyone see any pattern here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would guess that the question mark should be:

> $1$

The pattern I see:

> The picture is a tilted square, standing on one of its corners.
>  Along each edge of the square, the sum of the three numbers is $19$.
>  $2+11+6=19$, and $6+9+4=19$, and $4+14+?=19$, and $?+16+2=19$

Comment: Yup. Actually the puzzle is very nice example how visuals can be used as red-herrings in this type of things. It is so *hard* to ignore the lines...

Comment: @BmyGuest And that exactly what, in my opinion, makes this a bad puzzle.

Comment: You are great, Gamow. The line leading to center is blinding me ....

Answer (score 9):

I'd say:

> 1

Reasoning:

> the difference between the opposing pairs are rising primes.
>  2-4 (2)
>  11-14 (3)
>  1-6 (5)
>  16-9 (7)

Comment: if I am not wrong - in this way two possible answers are option A and C

Comment: He said rising, 3 is not rising.

Answer (score 1):

Diffenrence in right left top and bottom is two (9,11 and 14,16), and left right 2,4. Vertical it's five, so I guess, as mentioned above, it's one (1,6).

Answer (score -3):

2

Looking at opposites and ignoring the sign, starting at the '2' and rotating clockwise

2  - 4   = 2

11 - 14  = 3

6  - ?   =    should be 4 therefore the number required is 2

9  - 16  = 5

I know this is not the answer being looked for, but another pattern :)

Comment: How much is 9 - 16 again?